# torchaudio load for PCM file - EfficientConformer

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, speech-recognition, torchaudio

I'm struggling with parsing audio length in PCM file.

EfficientConformer use LibriSpeechDataset and the audio file format is **flac**, but in my case i'm using **pcm** files. EfficientConformer extracts audio length by torchaudio like this

```
audio_length = torchaudio.load(DATASET_PATH)[0].size(1)
```

But for my case, it doesn't work for **PCM** files, so I tried in different way.

#### What i did

get signal first by below code

```
signal = np.memmap(audio_path, dtype='h', mode='r').astype('float32')

if sum(abs(signal)) <= 80:
    raise ValueError('[WARN] Silence file in {0}'.format(audio_path))

return signal / 32767  # normalize audio
```

and then get waveform

```py
waveform = Tensor(signal).unsqueeze(0).t()
```

and then finally get size in dim(1)

```py
audio_length = waveform.size(1)
```

but it keep print **1** in terminal

This is my PCM dataset infos

- No header pcm files
- Sampling Fequency : 16000Hz
- Mono Channel

How to get audio length in pcm files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TorchAudio v0.12 or later, then using `torchaudio.io.StreamReader` allows to load PCM directly.

Ref: https://pytorch.org/audio/main/tutorials/streamreader_basic_tutorial.html#headerless-media

```py
s = StreamReader(src=PATH, format="s16le", option={"sample_rate": "16000"})
s.add_basic_audio_stream(frames_per_chunk=-1)
s.process_all_packets()
waveform, = s.pop_chunks
```